# Re-activating a deactivated Twitter account

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to reactivate a Twitter account that has been deactivated or deleted?

I just deactived my little sister's account but would like to someday re-activate it using the same email address and username.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you deactivate an account the username and email address will not be available for 30 days.  After the 30 day period they can be re-used by anyone - none of your twitter history or settings etc will be stored. It will essentially be a new clean account.

Taken from the [Twitter Help Center](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/107-my-profile-account-settings/articles/15358-how-to-deactivate-your-account)

> Deactivating your account permanently
>   removes your profile and information
>   from Twitter. Deactivated profiles
>   will take 30 days to clear from our
>   internal systems. While the
>   deactivation is being completed,
>   usernames or email addresses cannot be
>   used in the creation of a new account.
>
> **Before you do it, you should know...**
>
> - This is final and permanent.
> - You do not need to deactivate your account to change your username;
>     change it easily and at any time in
>     your account settings.
> - Unless you change your username and email before deactivation, you will
>     not be able to use them on a new
>     account for 30 days.
> - Account restoration is not available at this time.

In a slight contradiction of it's own Help Center, if you have deactivated an account by accident you *may* be able to restore it by selecting the `Restore my deleted account` option on this form http://support.twitter.com/forms/general

I would have thought that this would only be possible within the 30 day period from the date of deactivation.

Further details on Account Restoration can be found [here](http://support.twitter.com/articles/15359-about-account-restoration)

Comment: I have personal experience with deleting an account, waiting more than 30 days, then creating an account with the same email address and username. It works.